# Is it possible to override DidEnterBackground in another class?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, appdelegate

I am trying to create a reusable organised class to override AppDelegate class in IOS. Is there anyway to create a class that can override the AppDelegate's DidEnterBackground method?

I have tried create a class and inherits global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate and override the DidEnterBackground method, but it is not working.

```
 public class Testing : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
   public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
     {
            Console.WriteLine("App entering background state.");

        }
```

Comment: Did you replace `FormsApplicationDelegate` with your new subclass `Testing` in `AppDelegate.cs`

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm sorry, but I'm not quite understand your question, right now i have 2 classes 1 is AppDelegate.cs and another one is Testing.cs, where this Testing.cs will inherit global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate to override the DidEnterBackground method. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: You can not have multiple `UIApplicationDelegate`s in a single iOS app. The core one is defined in `AppDelegate.cs`. Since Forms uses `UIApplicationDelegate` to handle life cycle events, you can not remove it, but you can subclass it as you have but you would need to replace it in AppDelegate.cs... If you need to know about `DidEnterBackground` events in another class instance, then add an Event|Action or use the iOS notification center to broadcast the event that gets executed in the existing AppDelegate.DidEnterBackground

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you so much, now i understand.